# Would neutronium emit heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation

Since accelerating a charge creates EM radiation, and there are no charges in neutrons to be accelerated, would that mean neutronium emits no radiation?

Consequently, to preserve the second law of thermodynamics, would neutronium act as a perfect mirror for all EM radiation? (Or maybe be transparent to EM radiation)

Comment: I personally don't like the word "Neutronium" cause I think it's an oversimplification of what happens in a Neutron star.   But the formation of primarily Neutrons only happens inside the Neutron star, never on the surface, so it could never actually be seen.   That said, I think, a very cool question to think about, though it's a bit above my pay-grade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A neutron has an up quark with charge +2/3 and two down quarks each with charge -1/3. It has a magnetic moment and it does interact with electromagnetic radiation. So the premise seems incorrect.

Comment: I'm not sure it's quite that simple.   Mirrors and other reflective surfaces obviously have electric charges within them.